# XML RPC Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-rpc

I am trying to connect question2answer XMLRPC server [[Link](https://github.com/NoahY/q2a-xml-rpc)] with an android client [[Link](https://github.com/NoahY/q2android)] provided. But I am getting frollwing error when I fire android client:

```
org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException:
Org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParseException: expected: '>' actual: ''(position:END_TAG<?memb>@43668: 70 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41d07298)
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It look as if you were trying to parse an invalid xml structure.

The error itself points to a missing '>', like so:

```
<position>
  <stuff
</position>
```

The parser expects to find the '>' of the `stuff` tag, but finds the closing tag of `position`.

Try to extract the xml structure as a string and look for the error. You might also just paste it into an xml validator.

Comment: That is no easy to extract the XML structure. I tried via web browser an it says "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only." Also I tried to search the code for keyword "position". That is also not there in source of server.
Can somebody help me further to fix the problem?